# I have this ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition

Tags: solidity

I have another problem with my code and I don´t know how to solve it. This is a part of my code:

```
function countUsuarios() view public returns(uint){ //here is the error
      return usuariosAd.length;
    }
```

Also if I comment that order this is what happen:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.5;
contract Contract_Alba{
....
....
//function countUsuarios() view public returns(uint){ 
      //return usuariosAd.length;
   // }

} //Now I have the error here.
```

What do I have to do?
Thanks!

Comment: What's your solc compiler version ?

Comment: I have change my code to Pragma solidity ^0.5.16 and also my compiler.

Comment: This might be a syntax error. Check your code carefully or add all of your code in here. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it is a missing `{`, `}` or `;` but without the whole source code it is just a guess. Are contracts being imported from another file?

Comment: Solved! It was a missing }. Thank you so much!!